# React Passing Data to Stateful Component from Another Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components

Im trying to learn React and am creating a simple dropdown menu thats displays a list of sorting options for a user to choose. Clicking on whichever sort will sort a current HTMl Ul (alphabetical, oldest-newest, etc...)

I have a component called SortSelection that contains the dropdown menu and all the necessary logic to update the ul. Its called like this(inside another component):

```
      <div className="collectionsSortDropdownContainer">
        <SortSelection
          options={[
            { value: '-publishDate', name: 'Newest' },
            { value: '+publishDate', name: 'Oldest' },
          ]}
          handleSort={this.handleSort.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
```

Inside `SortSelection.jsx`, I currently have it written like this:

```
const SortSelection = ({
  options, extraClass, handleSort,
}) => {
   //...necessary logic
```

However, I realize that I should update SortSelection to be a stateful component since I'll be doing some extra UI stuff like displaying the current value of the Sort and adding a blue checkmark on the user-selected sort.

Im having trouble figuring out how to re-write my component to look like this:

```
class SortSelection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentSort: currentSort
    };
  }
}
```

**while also ensuring that the three necessary data parameters(options, extraClass, handleSort) are passed through for instantiating the component**. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **I assume you are trying to use some states inside your `SortSelection`**

You definitely don't need to use a class component for that, functional component will do as well because we have [React State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

So, in order to make it less complicated for you, just keep using a functional component like you already did:

**Just use `useState` like so:**

```
const { useState } = require("react")

const SortSelection = ({
  options, extraClass, handleSort,
}) => {
  const [currentSort, setCurrentSort] = useState();  //<-- useState hook
   //...necessary logic
   return (
     //...JSX
   )
}
```

---

`currentSort` is now a state, and every time you want to change that state and trigger a re-render, use `setCurrentSort`